# Translate excel vba to google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this function in `Excel 2010 vba` and I am not able to translate it to google script

```
Sub CalMoy()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dMWhit As Double
    Dim dMBlack As Double

    dMBlack = 0
    dMWhit = 0

    For i = 69 To 88
        j = 6
        For j = 6 To 32
            If (Evaluate(Chr(i) & j).Value = "Blanc") Then
                dMWhit = dMWhit + Evaluate("C" & j).Value
            End If
            If (Evaluate(Chr(i) & j).Value = "Noir") Then
                dMBlack = dMBlack + Evaluate("C" & j).Value
            End If
        Next j
        Evaluate(Chr(i) & 33).Value = dMWhit 
        Evaluate(Chr(i) & 34).Value = dMBlack 

    Next i
End Sub
```

I try with this code but it's not a succes

```
function CalMoy(){


    var dMBlack = 0;
    var dMWhit = 0;
    var col='';
    for (i = 69; i= 88; i++){
        var col=String.fromCharCode(i);
        var j = 6
        for (j = 6; j=32; j++){ 
          if(eval(col+ j + "value") = "Blanc"){
                 dMWhit = dMWhit + eval("C" & j).Value
          }
          if(eval(col+ j).Value = "Noir"){
                 dMBlack = dMBlack + eval("C" & j).Value
          }
        }
        eval(col + 33).Value = dMWhit 
        eval(col + 34).Value = dMBlack 

    }
}
```

Comment: "it's not a succes" you need to provide more information. Any error message? exception? compile error?

Answer (score 0):

In your `For` conditions, you have `i=88`, it should be `i<88`.

Also, in this line:

```
if(eval(col+ j + "value") = "Blanc"){
```

What are you trying to do?  If you are trying to concatenate text, you don't need to use the `eval()` method.  In any case, the syntax you are using for `eval()` is wrong.  And you can't evaluate text values.  The entire contents for the `eval()` method must be a string.  You must have double quotes at both ends.  Is "value" supposed to be a variable?  It doesn't make sense that it should be text, because the "value" string will never equal "Blanc".

This is what I have so far, but I can't go any further until you provide more info:

```
function CalMoy(){
  var dMBlack = 0;
  var dMWhit = 0;

  var col='';

  for (var i = 69; i < 88; i++){
    var col = String.fromCharCode(i);

      for (var j = 6; j<32; j++){ 
        if (eval("col + j + value") = "Blanc") {
          dMWhit = dMWhit + eval("C + j").Value
        }

        if (eval(col+ j).Value = "Noir") {
          dMBlack = dMBlack + eval("C" & j).Value;
        }
      }

      eval("col + 33").Value = dMWhit;
      eval("col + 34").Value = dMBlack;
    }
}
```